# Got error -1 from storage engine after truncate table

Tags: mysql

i have a innodb table named order_line that I wanted to truncate.
the message that I get was Got error -1 from storage engine and my table is completely lost!
luckily it's my development environment and not production!

how do I get the table back?
my disk space is 14 GB so that cannot be the problem

please help!

this is what my logfile says:

```
Version: '5.6.11'  socket: ''  port: 3308  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-09-16 12:41:47 134c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.

2013-09-16 12:41:47 134c  InnoDB: File name .\shopping\orderline.ibd
2013-09-16 12:41:47 134c  InnoDB: File operation call: 'create' returned OS error 105.
2013-09-16 12:41:47 134c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
2013-09-16 12:41:47 3220 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create file '.\shopping\orderline.ibd'

2013-09-16 12:41:47 3220 [ERROR] InnoDB: TRUNCATE TABLE shopping/orderline failed to create a new tablespace
2013-09-16 12:41:47 134c InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "shopping"."orderline" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
```

Comment: Open .err file and see if there is any issues

Comment: hi I added the logs from the .err file, but can't see what's wrong

Comment: error number 5 is a **Windows OS** error code indicates **input/output** error. You most likely have a hardware problem or make sure you have write permission to "\mysql\data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the following commands

```
 ALTER TABLE orderline DISCARD TABLESPACE

 DROP TABLE orderline 

 CREATE TABLE OrderLine ( 
     Your Table Field definitions here
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Alter Table & Drop Table will give errors but will remove the table from the data dictionary.

Ensure that you have access right to the Mysql5/Data/ directory